# SonataNewsBundle Entity Relationship Definition

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to create a new entity which will have relationship with SonataNewsBundle Post entity. But I can't find any example in the source how to define relation mapping in xml.
I've read all the configuration under Resources/config/doctrine, none of them had entity relation mapping. Or maybe Sonata use other method to define relationship? Give me some clues.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhhh... Found it...

It's in the DependencyInjection.

Sorry for the lame question